# Counting multiple keys in 1 MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I currently have a list of trades with the following columns:

```
TradeID, SellerID, FishType, Price, Qty
```

I am looking to get

1. The count of each **SellerID**
2. The **Qty** for each **FishType**

Currently, I have written a mapper that outputs < **FishType** , **Qty** > so as to sum up the **Qty** for each **FishType**. However, to get the count of **SellerID**, do I have to write a separate mapreduce task? Or is there a way for me to do so within the same mapreduce task?

I have considered using Counters, however, the sellerID in the records are unknown to me at the time of coding, and there are probably too many to keep track using counters. It is also an abuse of the Counter feature in my opinion.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way to do this is to have a separate mapreduce job.

The trickier way to do this, is to "overload" your keys. I'm guessing `SellerID` and `FishType` are both strings. When it is a `SellerID` add `"S:"` to the front of the string, and for `FishType` add `"F:"` to the front of the string.

Then, when you reach the reducer, you'll get one of two different types of calls of the `reduce` function: It starts with `"S:"`, in which case it is a `SellerID`, and one where It starts with `"F:"`, in which case it is a `FishType`. You have separate logic in the reducer based on this observation.

Finally, you use [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) (be careful of the `.mapred.` vs. `.mapreduce.` versions, they aren't compatible) to write out the results to two different directories: one for `FishType` and one for `SellerID`.

---

You might want to be using Pig or Hive for this.

Comment: I have been thinking about your "prefixing" solution. While I don't see why this will not work, i'm concerned if it actually defeats the whole purpose of the MapReduce framework. Since the framework will be unable to perform correct grouping and sorting of the intermediary keys, i.e. the keys are basically not sorted by either FishType or SellerID, the keys will not be contiguously fed into the reducer, hence, leading to a disjoined output.

Comment: All things `"F:Salmon"` will be sent to the same reducer and will be analyzed together. Is that what you mean by disjointed? All you are doing here really is overloading the keyspace to perform two jobs at once.

Comment: Ahh yes you are right. Still trying to wrap my head around the whole mapreduce framework. Thanks.